# Auto increment number on form submit based on same value input in another column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got this spreadsheet linked to a google form and in the form, user can key in the room number only while the seat number will be incremental.

So using google app script, I retrieved the user's form input for room number but I am having problem with auto-incrementing the Seat number based on the Room input.

Example in the image below: If user input Room 1 in the Google Form, the Seat number will be 18

Thank you so much to all of you in advanced!

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would fit this into your code (as you don't show any) but a formula to give the next available number (assuming assigned in ascending order) is:

```
=query(B:C,"select Max(C) where B=2 label Max(C)''")+1
```

to give `15` for your example, or `18` if changing the `2` to `1`.